# How to set up custom 401 error page or redirect in WSS3 SP2

Tags: wss-3.0, http-authentication, custom-errors

I've got a WSS3 sharepoint site that requires windows authentication both in IIS and via the Sharepoint site. What I would like to do is in the case that a user does not provide valid AD credentials they are redirected to a custom error page.

Currently, if the user immediately hits cancel when prompthey will see a plain text response of "401 UNAUTHORIZED". If they make an attempt and then hit cancel they instead see a blank page.

I have looked into several options such as customErrors, httpModule interception (only saw examples for this after the user is authenticated), IIS Url rewrites (didn't see how this could help).

Is there a good way to do this?